# How to parse a CSV file using A1/B2 as cell value using apache commons CSV?

Tags: csv, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

My CSV file cell contains B1 B2 ,C3,.. as records. Can I parse such CSV file using Apache commons CSV library? I know WE can define custome heders for columns(like A,B,..) but can we define rows also as numbers?

Comment: No one can help?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but whatever. :) Maybe I don't understand your question, but rows are already defined as numbers. The array is indexed using the header, and then you index into that array using a row number.